# Speed up parsing function with multiprocessing

Tags: python, parsing, request, python-requests, multiprocessing

i'm trying to get mean birthday of your friends through parsing. But it takes about a minute. I tried to speed up with multiprocess, but got error. How can i speed up my function. Also tried session.get, but it make no input on speed of function

```
def mean_friend_age(idi):
    mean_age_id = []
    mean_age = []
    age_number = []
    session = requests.Session()
    r_mean_id = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get? user_id='+ str(idi) + '&v=5.52&access_token=TOKEN')
    json_mean_id = r_mean_id.text
    string_mean_id = json_mean_id[34:-3]
    mean_ids_list = string_mean_id.split(',')
    for item in mean_ids_list:
        mean_age_id.append(item)
    for item in mean_age_id:
        req_mean = session.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.getuser_id='+ str(item) + '&v=5.52&access_token=TOKEN&fields=counters,sex,bdate,country,hometown,lists,last_seen,verified,occupation,wall_comments,can_write_private_message, can_see_audio, can_see_all_posts, can_post')
        json_mean = req_mean.json()
        for item in json_mean['response']:
            json_dict = item
        while True:
            try:
                age = json_dict['bdate']
                break
            except KeyError:
                age = '0'
                break
        mean_age.append(age)
    for item in mean_age:
        if len(item) >= 7:
            dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(item, '%d.%m.%Y')
            item_number = get_age(dt_obj)
            age_number.append(item_number)
    mean = statistics.mean(age_number)
    return mean
```

then i try to multiprocess and get error:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        a = p.map(mean_friend_age, '181145622')



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
return list(map(*args))
File "<ipython-input-63-2984c547fa8d>", line 18, in mean_friend_age
age = json_dict['bdate']
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'json_dict' referenced before 
assignment

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-65-39dd60c6a8fb> in <module>()
  1 if __name__ == '__main__':
  2     with Pool(5) as p:
----> 3         a = p.map(mean_friend_age, '181145622')

/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, 
iterable, chunksize)
264         in a list that is returned.
265         '''
--> 266         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, 
chunksize).get()
267 
268     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
642             return self._value
643         else:
--> 644             raise self._value
645 
646     def _set(self, i, obj):

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'json_dict' referenced before 
assignment
```

How can i speed up function?

Comment: This has nothing to do with multiprocessing. There is an issue in your code itself.

Comment: it works without multiprocessing

Comment: Only by coincidence. Look, you have completely misunderstood what multiprocessing does; you can't just pass it a function containing a loop and expect it to parallelise it. What is actually happening here is that `pool.map` is iterating over the iterable you pass it, which is a string; so it is doing the function once with `idi` as 1, once as 8, and so on; and given that those are not valid values for the API, you get an empty response. You need to rethink this from the start.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is simple.

Here in `for` loop you assign `item` to `json_dict` variable:

```
for item in json_mean['response']:
    json_dict = item
```

And then you want to access this `json_dict` in another `while` loop:

```
while True:
    try:
        age = json_dict['bdate']
```

The problem here is `scoping`. So every variable in almost every language (f.e `var` in JS is different) has a scope. It means that if you create it in a block of code (which in languages like C/C++/Java and so on is between `{}` and in Python it is done by indenting the code) your variable "is alive" until you leave this block of code.

In the code you presented, not only you lose the scope of `json_dict` variable (so it is not known to the compiler, or in this current example the interpreter) after leaving your for loop and you cannot access it from your while loop, but additionally you `overwrite` it with every iteration of your for loop (I don't know if thats what you really wanted to do).

The solution would be creating `json_dict` above for loop (and f.e assigning it to `None`, whatever) and then accessing it both from `for` and `while` loops